# How to check current status of a latest Data Factory Pipeline run with Pipeline name?

Tags: azure-data-factory

Is it possible to check the current status of a latest Data Factory Pipeline run with Pipeline name using .NET SDK? This is what I tried now:

```
             using (var client = new DataFactoryManagementClient(cred) {SubscriptionId = subscriptionId})
            {
                RunQueryFilter pipeline = new RunQueryFilter("PipelineName", "Equals", new List<string> { "Pipeline" });                

                var before = DateTime.UtcNow;
                var after = before.AddHours(-24);
                var param = new RunFilterParameters(after, before, null, new List<RunQueryFilter> { pipeline }, null);
                PipelineRunsQueryResponse pipelineResponse = client.PipelineRuns.QueryByFactory(
                                                                        resourceGroup,
                                                                        dataFactoryName, param
                                                                    );



            }

How do I get latest run id?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out -

```
using (var client = new DataFactoryManagementClient(cred) {SubscriptionId = subscriptionId})
            {
                RunQueryFilter pipeline = new RunQueryFilter("PipelineName", "Equals", new List<string> { "Pipeline" });                
                var pipelineRuns = new RunQueryOrderBy("RunEnd", "DESC");
                var before = DateTime.UtcNow;
                var after = before.AddHours(-24);
                var param = new RunFilterParameters(after, before, null, new List<RunQueryFilter> { pipeline }, new List<RunQueryOrderBy> { pipelineRuns });
                PipelineRunsQueryResponse pipelineResponse = client.PipelineRuns.QueryByFactory(
                                                                        resourceGroup,
                                                                        dataFactoryName, param
                                                                    );

                var runId = pipelineResponse?.Value?[0]?.RunId;

            }
```

Comment: You should write this up as an answer and accept it, that would be useful to future folks who find this through search.

Comment: Done, Thank you!

Comment: You can still accept your own response as the answer :-)